# I created a library. How do i set up unique permissions when i can't even click Shared with

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

My library is automatically shared with everyone and i would like to change that so i can share with specific people

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could go to library settings-> Permissions for this library, click Stop Inheriting Permissions to set up unique permissions.

[image]
[image]